# how to cancel unconfirmed transaction in blockchain.info

Tags: blockchain.info, unconfirmed-transactions

Ok I know this is a much asked question but I have looked at the other answers and none of them were helpful.

I sent almost $2000 in BTC from my blockchain.info wallet to a mixer that has an input address that is only valid for 24 hours.  The fee blockchain.info recommended was 0.000079 which seemed a bit low so I upped it to 0.00011 but apparently that amounts to about 57 sat/B which is way too low to get confirmed in a timely manner.

If it takes more than 24 hours to get confirmed then I assume I've lost $2000.

There doesn't seem to be any facility in blockchain.info to kill an unconfirmed transaction.

Am I totally screwed?  I have an electrum wallet, is there any way I can import my blockchain.info wallet without the unconfirmed transaction?  i.e. Get my original balance back.  Is there anything I can do?

I know similar questions have been asked but I couldn't find any answer that applies, or maybe there isn't one.  My HUGE mistake was placing any trust at all in the blockchain.info wallet recommended fee.  Yeah I'm a newbie idiot but wow this has been an expensive lesson.

UPDATE

I have contacted the mixer and much to my relief they say the receiving address will be valid for a week for unconfirmed transactions.  So my question becomes what happens with a blockchain.info wallet, if a send remains unconfirmed for a few days?  Will the send be cancelled?  Is it likely a 0.00011 fee be enough for it to ever be confirmed?

Comment: Can you submit a higher fee double-spend transaction?

Comment: I am not sure quite how a mixer works but maybe the company that owns it can still access the address if you tell them which one you used

Comment: @NULL I don't think there is any facility in blockchain.info wallet to double spend.  The mixer in this case, makes it clear the receiving address is only valid for 24 hours.

Comment: related: [How to unstuck a low-fee transaction with blockchain.info?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/53852/5406)

Answer (score 1):

> I upped it to 0.00011 but apparently that amounts to about 57 sat/B which is way too low to get confirmed in a timely manner.

According to the 21.co fee estimator:

https://bitcoinfees.21.co/

A 57 satoshi per byte transaction should be confirmed within 35 to 600 minutes (10 hours). It should go through.

Answer (score 0):

> So my question becomes what happens with a blockchain.info wallet, if
>   a send remains unconfirmed for a few days?

nothing.

> Will the send be cancelled?

no

> Is it likely a 0.00011 fee be enough for it to ever be confirmed?

nobody knows about future