# Transactions that cannot be part of block

Tags: transactions, blockchain, unconfirmed-transactions, block

Is it possible to have a "unlucky" transaction that can never be part of block? Meaning grouping it with other transactions never results in a valid block?

[Edit]
By not being in valid block, I meant no valid nonce is found with given target difficulty. It seems mathematically, this is possible and what happens to transaction (if there is no expirey) in this case?

Comment: The number of possible blocks including that transaction is a number with tens of thousands of digits. You're imagining there would be no possible nonce for any of them?

Answer (score 2):

No, if the transaction is valid then it can always be included in a block if a valid nonce/extra nonce is found.

Answer (score 1):

No. By the definition, any valid transaction can be placed in block. If something in block invalidates it - this is only an array of random bytes, not a valid bitcoin transaction.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the transaction may be pending for hours, or even days, yes: [it can happen](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_expiration) and it's part of Bitcoin Core protocol.

You may also want to have a look at [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/53852/how-to-unstuck-a-low-fee-transaction-with-blockchain-info)