# What to do about "stuck" transactions?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, transaction-fees, mempool

(Copied from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/7pdjsr/dealing_with_stuck_bitcoins/))

Hey. I recently made a bitcoin transaction for the first time in a while. The transaction fees have gone through the roof (!!) since the last time I used it, and I figured it would be no issue to use the default fee on my electrum wallet (104 sat/byte).

I now realize this was a big mistake. My transaction is stuck in mempool and I don't know what to do about it.

What should I do? How long do transactions stay in mempool before they are not considered "sent" anymore and I can spend the bitcoins in another transaction? Is there a way to retroactively attach a higher transaction fee to my transaction?

I'd really appreciate any help with this. Having your money stuck in digital limbo sucks.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered [here on Stackexchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/53852/how-to-unstuck-a-low-fee-transaction-with-blockchain-info)

You can find some additional information in the [article](https://bitcoinmagazine.com/articles/what-to-do-if-your-bitcoin-transaction-gets-stuck-1481042383/)

PS. Right now stuck about 0.07 BTC thanks to blockchain.info fee calculator. Just waiting, I'm not in a rush